# Reload the page with parameter triggered by JavaScript dropdown change event

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I want a form to be reloaded and preselected with the selection made. Here's the HTML form I have:

```
<form name='vehicleform'>

<select name='vehiclelist'>
  <option value=''>Select</option>
  <option value='bus'>Bus</option>
  <option value='bike'>Bike</option>
  <option value='car'>Car</option>
</select>

<input type='text' name='current'></input>

</form>
```

When the user opens the page for the first time the dropdown box will be on the **Select** option by default and the textbox (current) will be empty.

When the user selects any option from dropdown the page needs to reload and that dropdown item should be selected and the value of that dropdown should be in the text input field.

What's the JavaScript function that I need to make this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
<select name='soemname' id="myid" onchange="document.location.href = 'page.php?var=' + this.value">
  <option value=''>Select</option>
  <option value='bus'>Bus</option>
  <option value='bike'>Bike</option>
  <option value='car'>Car</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('myid').value = "<?php echo $_GET['var'];?>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

[sAc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351845/js-how-to-reload-the-same-webpage-with-param-on-dropdown-change-event/3351856#3351856) tells you how you can use the onchange event to modify the *location.href* property.  This will work, but it's not accessible to users with JS disabled.  I would set a url in the form's action attribute and have the select element submit the form in the *onchange* event.  This way, users with JavaScript can still press the return key to reload the page with the same effect:

```
<?php $sel = isset($_GET['vehiclelist']) ? $_GET['vehiclelist'] : ""; ?>
<form name='vehicleform' action="thispage.php">

<select name='vehiclelist' onchange="this.parentNode.submit();">
  <option value='' >Select</option>
  <option value='bus' <?php echo $sel == "bus" ? "selected" : "";?>>Bus</option>
  <option value='bike' <?php echo $sel == "bike" ? "selected" : "";?>>Bike</option>
  <option value='car' <?php echo $sel == "car" ? "selected" : "";?>>Car</option>
</select>

<input type='text' name='current' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['var']); ?>"></input>

</form>
```

The end result is a feature that is accessible to users with JavaScript disabled too.

Comment: @sAc: ha, I can relate to that :)

Comment: Actually, I have to submit this form separately to store textbox(current) value in database using a submit button(missed in question). Therefore I have to call another script on submit of this form to store textbox value in database. I think js is only option in this case?

Comment: @NAVEED: you can specify multiple submit buttons for a form and, if the *name* attribute is provided with them you can detect which button was used to send the form.  If you have a server-side condition to catch when the "real" submit is sent and record the data in the database.  See also http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5242116.html.

Comment: HTML injection vulnerability in the input value. Remember `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: @bobince: right you are. This sort of stuff doesn't always occur to me when I'm writing answers here, thanks for the nudge.