# Select a Dropdown, Change the JS Value and Reload the Page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a script that when I select an option from a dropdown box, it does the following:

1. change the value of the "var pick_" based on this option;
2. reload the page; and
3. maintain the selected option in the dropdown and "var pick_".

How can I make this happens using Javascript? I have looked into [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351845/reload-the-page-with-parameter-triggered-by-javascript-dropdown-change-event) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699316/how-to-reload-same-page-after-change-the-select-box-option) but the selection option does not get maintained after reloading the page.

Here is my script:

```
var pick_ = 1

<select id = "selectX" onchange = "getSelectValue('selectX');">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>
     <option>5</option>
</select>

function getSelectValue(selectID){
     pick_ = document.getElementById(selectID).value;
     location.reload(); 
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is actually uses the same technology with sultan khan's answer, but you need to retrieve the value after a reload.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if (localStorage.pick) {
        var sel = document.querySelector('#selectX');
        sel.value = localStorage.pick;
    }
});

function getSelectValue(){
    var sel = document.querySelector('#selectX');
    localStorage.pick = sel.value;
    location.reload();
}
```

then in your HTML

```
<select id = "selectX" onchange = "getSelectValue();">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Although this answer works, it is bad practice to save arbitrary data to cookies. This is how DOM turn into slugs. Only use cookies if they are absolutely necessary.

Comment: @SynchroDynamic which code of it uses cookie? don't you see it uses `localStorage`?

Answer (score 2):

you can store somewhere by using local-storage or cookie or any server-side if you want to persist the variable data.

```
var pick_ = 1

<select id = "selectX" onchange = "getSelectValue('selectX');">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>
     <option>5</option>
</select>

function getSelectValue(selectID){
     pick_ = document.getElementById(selectID).value;
     localStorage.pick_ =pick_ 
     pick_ = localStorage.getItem("pick_");
     location.reload(); 
}
```

Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the value of the dropdown to some globally available position like cookies or local storage.

Note: The snippet does not run here but will work just fine.

```js
function getSelectValue(selectID){
         pick_ = document.getElementById('selectX').value;
         localStorage.setItem("lastSelectedValue", pick_); 
         location.reload(); 
}
function getLastSelectedValue(){
         var value = localStorage.getItem("lastSelectedValue")
         if(value )
         {
            document.getElementById('selectX').value = value  ;
         }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload = 'getLastSelectedValue()'>
<select id = "selectX" onchange = "getSelectValue('selectX');">
     <option>option 1</option>
     <option>option 2</option>
     <option>option 3</option>
     <option>option 4</option>
     <option>option 5</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `localStorage` is different from cookie, better to rename the functions to avoid confusions

Comment: @am05mhz thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer will be use cookies.

```
function getSelectValue(selectID){
    pick_ = document.getElementById(selectID).value;
    document.cookie = "pick="+pick_;
    location.reload(); 
}
```

and the next time you reload the page check for the cookie name "pick" if it exists, pick it's value otherwise choose default

Answer (score 0):

If you require the page to reload then you can set the parameter in your URL. You can then get the parameter. There are many other ways to do this, I doubt there is a reason to store this in any way.

To achieve this, I did the following:

1. give the options a value.
2. Create a function to set the parameter in the URL `setSelectValue(key, value)`
3. Create a function to get this value when the page is reloaded `getParameter(name, url)`
4. Then you just enjoy!

   ```
   <select id = "selectX" onchange="setSelectValue('id', this.value);">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
   <script>
       var pick_ = getParameter("id");
       var selectedOption = document.getElementById("selectX");
       selectedOption.options[(pick_ - 1)].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
       function setSelectValue(key, value) {//We can set a Parameter in our URL like this
           key = encodeURI(key);
           value = encodeURI(value);
           var kvp = document.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
           var i = kvp.length;
           var x;
           while (i--)//
           {
               x = kvp[i].split('=');
               if (x[0] === key)
               {
                   x[1] = value;
                   kvp[i] = x.join('=');
                   break;
               }
           }
           if (i < 0) {
               kvp[kvp.length] = [key, value].join('=');
           }
           document.location.search = kvp.join('&');
       }
       function getParameter(name, url) {//We can then return the URL like this
           if (!url)
               url = window.location.href;
           name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
           var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                   results = regex.exec(url);
           if (!results)
               return 1;//if no parameters return the first option
           if (!results[2])
               return '';
           return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
       }
   </script>
   ```

I hope this works per your requirements.